# "Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2" Error when using scaler.inverse_transform()

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, feature-engineering

I am building a Neural Network, I do a transformation to all the data sample before the split to test and train samples:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(0, 1))
dataset= scaler.fit_transform(dataset)
```

After splitting I check the dimensions of the target_test and target_train samples:

```
Target_train.ndim
Target_test.ndim
```

The dimensions are equal to 2.
When I try to inverse the transformation:

```
Target_train = scaler.inverse_transform([Target_train])
Target_test = scaler.inverse_transform([Target_test])
```

I get the following error:
Found array with dim 3. Estimator expected <= 2.

I am confused to why I am having this error since the dimensions are equal to 2.
Any ideas on what could be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a singleton `[Target_train]` which has one more dimension, it is 1 x [samples x features], just pass `Target_train` alone.